# how to update table from linked server in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have few tables I need to load from linked firebird server into SQL Server from time to time. I use statement like this:

```
SELECT * into dekr FROM OPENQUERY ( [PLINK] ,'select * from dekr' )
```

It  takes a while since it's going over network etc, is there a way to update once created
table dekr only with changes since last time?
thanks

Comment: I have done this before but I would need to see your table definitions to give you a decent answer.

Comment: I have more then one table to import to our DW but not sure how can table definition help you in answer? I can post one of them though, no problem.